# Is there any symfony bundle that use facebook/twitter/google+ for authentication?

Tags: symfony

Is there any symfony bundle that use facebook/twitter/google+ for authentication that works with symfony 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) with [FOSFacebookBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle) (for Facebook) and [FOSTwitterBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSTwitterBundle) (for Twitter). But there is actually no bundle for Google+.

Comment: FOSFacebookBundle and FOSTwitterBundle are NOT MAINTAINED and recommend HWIOAuthBundle.

Answer (score 15):

Checkout [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) bundle, it [has over 10](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L30) authentication providers